# javascript finding a key in nested object

Tags: javascript

I have an object called _test shaped in the below form where the first element is id and the second is name:

```
"_test": [
    {id:1, name:andy},{id:2, name:james}, {id:3, name:mike} 
]
```

I then have another field called key. the values that key takes on can equal values of id in the subs

```
key
```

I currently use

```
_test.flatMap( c => c.id).find(elem => elem == key) || null
```

How can I get this to return the name? I'm at a loss and having a major brain fart.

Comment: Arrays don't have keys. They have numeric indexes. You probably should be using an array of objects, not an array of arrays.

Comment: hi i made an error in wording. i am actually working nested objects.
the object has ids and names, there are 3 nested objects within, if that makes sense!

I have edited my question now

Comment: For future reference, get familiar with [how to access and process objects, arrays, or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212), and what [objects](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and [arrays](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array#array_literal_notation) look like in literal notation. Then [edit] and provide the literal form of your object.

Comment: `flatMap()` is converting the array of objects into an array just containing the IDs. Don't do that.

Comment: hi I made an edit after my edit! Sorry I'm still very new to js, and I wanted to say I really appreciate all the corrections, and notes on syntax

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+find+object+by+value+of+property) of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](/q/7364150/4642212). It’s `yourObject._test.find(({ id }) => id === key)?.name ?? null`. Note that `find` already returns `undefined`, when nothing is found; using `null` as an alternative doesn’t really make a huge difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the name for a given `id` via:

```js
const
  _test = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Andy'  },
    { id: 2, name: 'James' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Mike'  }
  ],
  key = 2,
  { name } = _test.find(({ id }) => id === key) ?? {};

console.log(name); // James
```

Answer (score -1):

actually is pretty easy, you just need to use `find` on your array, it takes a function as an argument.

pd: when doing `([id, name])` I'm destructuring the array, you can change that to:

```
names.find(entry => key === entry[0])
```

```js
const names = [
  [1, 'andy'],
  [2, 'james'],
  [3, 'mike']
];
const key = 3;
const solution = names.find(([id, name]) => key === id)

console.log("solution => ", solution)
console.log("just the name => ",
  solution[1]);
```